# The command tail -f not working as expected

Tags: logging, grep, sh, alpine-linux, tail

There's a log file that continuously gets lines written from a local server.

I want to audit any changes made to that file, specifically for the term **restarting**. I tried this:

```
while [ $(tail -f ../debug.log | grep -c "restarting") -eq 0 ]; do echo "Restart"; done
```

The problem is that `grep -c "restarting"` returns nothing, whilst `grep "restarting"` returns the matched line. Weird is that the `cat` shows that the line is there, but the `while` loop just keeps looping indefinitely. What's wrong?

Also, `echo "Restart"` is just for testing purposes eventually I would `pkill` the process and exit with code 0.

If possible to run the `while` loop in the background would be a huge plus.

Can someone please help me get this working? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You won't be able to count in grep until the output is closed. i,e.tail -f is stopped.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's already answered at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/631173/133219

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to close this question @EdMorton as you've already gave an answer using `awk`.

I eventually went for `sed`, and created a file named **on_restart.sh**:

```
#!/bin/sh
tail -f ../debug.log | sed -e '/process restarting/ q'
pkill -9 process; exit 0
```

Running that file in the background is as easy as `./on_restart.sh &`.

Comment: Also, `sed` seemed more practical than `grep` for this case scenario